# Nodejs on azure : server not starting before the first request

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have a weird probleme, when starting listening I run the following function :

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, async function () {
  await db.init().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    console.error("Shutting down because there was an error setting up the database.");
    process.exit(1);
  });
  await recordsDb.init().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    console.error("Shutting down because there was an error setting up the records database.");
    process.exit(1);
  });
  //this db object will be used by controllers..
  app.set('db',db);
});
```

the problem is that the function doesn't run before the first request (and so the first request always fail), am I missing something ?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe your Azure setup a bit more?  What services in Azure are you using (Web App, Function, VM)?  What size your you using (Free, Basic, Standard)?  Have you configured always on, etc?

Comment: I think it's a webapp, free (azure for student), and I'm not sure how to configure this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first [scale up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-scale#scale-up-your-pricing-tier) your Web App Service plan, then you can enable **Always On**.  By default, apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time. If your app runs continuous WebJobs or runs WebJobs triggered using a CRON expression, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably.  Free Azure web apps do not support Always On.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure

Comment: Thank you so much ! will this make on listen run before sending requests as well ?

Comment: Always On is part of it, you can also do app initialization.  Check out https://twentytech.net/azure/advanced-configurations-for-node-js-on-azure-webapps/